# glassfish generated folder keep growing

Tags: java, glassfish, centos7

I have a centos 7 64 bit server with the glassfish 4 installed and running normally, my problem is that every time I restart the server, in the generated / jsp folder, all files in my application are added until there is no more space left in the disk.

Does anyone know of a way for these files to be created only once?

Comment: What files is it creating exactly? If it's "running normally", how do you get it to stop filling your disk?

Comment: when I restart the glassfish, the generated folder files are duplicated, until the centos has no more disk space

Answer (score 1):

we have same issue and found that this is "known issue" in glassfish

for example guys discussed the issue the thread
[The generated folder in Glassfish keeps growing every time the server is restarted](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-30867)

what we are going to do is add clean up script into a command file that starts glassfish server the sample of cleanup script you can get here
[Utility scripts to clean up glassfish domain folders to avoid permgen exception](https://gist.github.com/nyxcalamity/10667381)